# Create a new column based on other columns in existing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two dataframes:

```
test=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[6,7,8,9,0]})
test2=pd.DataFrame({"z":[1],"p":[6]})
```

which result respectively in:

```
    x   y
0   1   6
1   2   7
2   3   8
3   4   9
4   5   0
```

and

```
    z   p
0   1   6
```

What is the best way to create a column "s" in table test that is equal to: 
`test["s"]=test["x"]*test2["z"]+test2["p"]`

when I try the above expression I get the following output:

```
    x    y      s
0   1    6     7.0
1   2    7     NaN
2   3    8     NaN
3   4    9     NaN
4   5    0     NaN
```

but I want the result along all the rows. I have researched something about the apply method or so called vectorized operations but I don't really know how to undertake the problem.

Expected output:

```
    x    y      s
0   1    6     7.0
1   2    7     8.0
2   3    8     9.0
3   4    9     10.0
4   5    0     11.0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if `test2` has more than one row?

Comment: please show your desired output..does ```test2``` always have just one row?

Comment: I have updated my question with desired output. Yes, Test2 has always one row.

Comment: if `test` has always one row, then just use their values as scalars. Instant broadcasting, no need to worry about index matching etc. Simply `test['x'] * test2['z'].item() + test2['p'].item()` . I believe `.item` will be deprecated in next pandas version, so you can also simply use `.loc[0]` instead.

Comment: `test['s'] = test.x * test2.z.loc[0] + test2.p.loc[0]`

Comment: I think a `DataFrame` is a bit overkill for holding scalars. Probably better to place them in a dict that way you don't have to fuss with the annoyance of trying to grab a single item from a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution,  I took Trenton_M suggestions.

```
test=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[6,7,8,9,0]})
test2=pd.DataFrame({"z":[1],"p":[6]})
```

Multiplication process:

```
test["s"] = test['x'] * test2.z.loc[0] + test2.p.loc[0]
test
```

Output:

```
    x   y   s
0   1   6   7
1   2   7   8
2   3   8   9
3   4   9   10
4   5   0   11
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication), like this:

```
test['s'] = test.x * test2.z[0] + test2.p[0]
```